# Add to module manifest Provider

Tags: android

There is a module (library) in which I want to add a provider. The main application to which this library is added can contain its own provider, as well as some attributes in the application block.

My app manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    //...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.appFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

My library manifest

```
 <application>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.libFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/libpaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

And when compiling, the merge of the manifests fails(*Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs*).

> /Users/nameny/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-67
> Error:    Attribute
> provider#androidx.core.content.FileProvider@authorities
> value=(ru.mydomain.myapplication.appFileProvider) from
> AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-67  is also present at [:mylibrary]
> AndroidManifest.xml:12:13-67
> value=(ru.mydomain.myapplication.libFileProvider).    Suggestion: add
> 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to  element at
> AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-29:20 to override.
> /Users/nameny/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:28:17-50
> Error:    Attribute
> meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource
> value=(@xml/filepaths) from AndroidManifest.xml:28:17-50  is also
> present at [:mylibrary] AndroidManifest.xml:17:17-49
> value=(@xml/libpaths).    Suggestion: add
> 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to  element at
> AndroidManifest.xml:26:13-28:53 to override.
> /Users/nameny/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
> Error:    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 23
> declared in library [:mylibrary]
> /Users/nameny/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/mylibrary/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
> as the library might be using APIs not available in 19    Suggestion:
> use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,         or increase
> this project's minSdk version to at least 23,         or use
> tools:overrideLibrary="ru.nymy.mylibrary" to force usage (may lead to
> runtime failures)

How is this problem solved?

Comment: Which error did you get at merging?

Comment: got the same error.
The exact error is `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs` :D
so the logs in the question are showing the exact error.